# CakePHP magic find inflects to lower case

Tags: cakephp

I'm migrating to postgres from mysql and having an issue with "magic find" and case sensitivity in Postgres.

Model->findByFirstname inflects to "Model"."firstname" and Postgres can't find that column, since it's named "Firstname" in my db.

Any ideas?

Comment: I highly recommend not to use magic finders. They are not very nice to handle - and there is no IDE typehinting or help of any kind for it. So there is basically no advantange of using them in the first place IMO.

Comment: How about the most obvious one, change your DB schema to follow the [**cake naming conventions**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions)?

Comment: True, using `firstname` as field name would help if one really needs to use it.

Comment: Or use a find() with proper conditions. I never really liked or used the magic finders because of the lack of control.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Changing DB schema feels risky since I reference the columns in code in a lot of places. I'm going to rewrite with regular find()-expressions instead, I think it's the most controlled way to migrate. But for future projects I'll stick to the naming conventions :)

Answer (score 0):

You can override the magic handling of `FindBy<Fieldname>` by adding the PHP handler `__call` to your `AppModel` base class. This will be called for each magic find method.

The first parameter is the function name, and the second parameter are the function arguments.

```
public function __call($method, $params)
{
    if (strpos($method, 'findBy') === 0 || strpos($method, 'findAllBy') === 0)
    {
        // customer handler here
        return ....
    }
    return parent::__call($method,$params);
}
```

For your custom handler. You can do something like `return $this->find(...)`. Where you apply conditions that are for `findBy` or `findAllBy`. Except use the case sensitive field name for the condition. That field name can be extracted from `$method`.